# Is there any way to convert any other crypto currency into ADA?

Tags: wallet, cardano-address

I want make a POS(Point of Sales) system for Cardano to accept payments, in which I need to convert other coins (e.g. ether) into ADA and store those ADA funds into Cardano wallet.

I want to make something like this, here is example
[Changenow](https://changenow.io/exchange?from=eth&to=ada)
[coingate](https://coingate.com/pos)

please suggest me any idea related to how to exchange currencies and how to do it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exchange non-ADA on the fly for ADA then you will need to use an exchange. Take a look at Minswap or Sundaeswap etc as they might have APIs that you can use.

DCSpark are also looking to offer EVM related services (named Milkomeda) but I'm not sure how far along they are.